# How to build a predictive model that uses only a subset of training factors , for testing?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, supervised-learning

Generally, all the predictive algorithms work as follows :

```
input factors : x1,x2,x3,x4...xn<br>
responses: y1,y2..ym <br>
```

and the model (say M) built gives the predicted output as `M(x1,x2,x3..,xn)=(Y1,Y2,..,Yk)`.
Now suppose while training the model I have all the input factors and responses as given above 
 **but while predicting I have only some 'j' input factors (where j < n)**. 
Eg. **I have x1,x2,x3..,xj and I want to do M(x1,x2,x3..xj).** 
Can I still use my model for prediction ?

Comment: So, rather than using statistical formulas to explain, can you give an example? Are you saying that, if I were using `data(mtcars)` and trying to predict `mpg`, that you have "cyl" , "disp" ,"hp"  , "drat", "wt",   "qsec", "vs",   "am",   "gear" and "carb" in you training dataset but might only have "cyl" , "disp" ,"hp"  , "drat", "wt",   "qsec", "vs" and  "am" in the test? So you are missing "am" and "gear? Or are you saying you don't have the degrees of freedom to use all j predictors?

Comment: @jason Yes, that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach which is statistically sound is to build an ensemble of models using only subset of features (random) in each simple one. For example consider building something like random forest, but each tree can only use 80% of features (classical RF removes features in each node, and I am talking here about removing them globally). Then, once you train your ensemble, and you get a testing point which does not have some features - you simply use only these models from the ensemble, which are consistent with observation (were trained on features which are available). Given enough weak learners in ensemble this should work well.

Comment: That will do, but I think we can't change the model in OP's case.

Comment: In any case, as long as you don't know the missing values, your predictions for those particular observations will be only as good as the predictions obtained by a model trained using only those available variables.

Comment: @Gaurav - obviously true. Simply ensemble approach makes it statistically sound distinction between "lack of feature" and "feature having some predefined value" (such as 0 or imputed mean/median). Furthermore, randomization and ensembling makes it possible to build a model able to comprehend many missing values without exponential number of models required for "strict" solution.

Answer (score 0):

For most models you can't. You will either have to remove the additional j-n inputs that you don't have in your predicting set and retrain the model using only j variables. Otherwise you will have to approximate the missing values.

I suggest you read some theory on the topic of 'handling missing values' in statistics for more details on how to treat such situations. There are some models which allow for missing values as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends. Most common models can't handle `NA` values in the inputs, but you can substitute mean or median values from the training set for missing inputs. If missing predictors are of low importance, predictions could be good enough. Anyway, first thing to try is to replace missing variables with mean values from the training set and benchmark your model.

Comment: just bear in mind, that imputing missing values is **statistically wrong**. It can work, as any heuristic, but from theoretical point of view it is completely wrong.